# Can I remove the query string from PHP after the page loads?

Tags: php, string, uri

I have a URL like :http://localhost/foldername/page?name=xyz after page loads.

The page contents is coming by fetching the data from database with **name=xyz**.
But I want to the URL like : http://localhost/foldername/page/xyz after the page loads. Is there any way ?

Comment: use `.htaccess` to rewrite you url

Comment: mod_rewrite my friend. You are using apache or nginx?

Comment: I am using Apache ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a `.htaccess` file inside `foldername` and put this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Access it from browser 
http://localhost/foldername/page/xyz

now you can access `name` in **index.php**  with get request  $_GET['name'];

Comment: Thank You Brother !! Let me try this option also.

Comment: let me know if you facing any problem.

Comment: Brother its still the same. Actually when I enter http://localhost/foldername/page/xyz is also working now. but the automatically its give the above URL.

Comment: No brother .. I am new to this. This one is my first project.

Comment: This is my lik which redirect to the respective page : <a href="category.php?name=<?php echo $row["category_slug"]; ?>" >Read More</a>

I stores the name in the variable  from the page URL $name=$_GET['name'];

Then I run the Query to fetch the data from database to display the content.

Comment: As per your suggestion I have enter the below code to the .htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category_detail/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ category_detail.php?name=$1 [L]

</IfModule>

Comment: make it <a href="page/<?php echo $row["category_slug"]; ?>

Comment: Hey Brother ,,,,Thank You ... Its perfectly working now ... Thank for your support ... I was unaware of the fact the I need to change this anchor tag too ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, get url and use strtok for clear get value in url

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = strtok($url, '?');
    $get_name = $_GET['name'];
    $url = "Location: ".$url."/".$get_name;
    header($url);    
}
```

Comment: Thank You !! Its working ... The URL I want to be in address bar I got it. But as it is redirected to new URL then how can I get the **name** ? As I am fetching the content of the page via that name column from database. How can I store that name in variable so that I can fetch accordingly after page being redirect to new URL?